# Connection to server show the same Alert Dialog (Even if there's no connection)

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, alert

I want to know if i have connection to the server and if there's no connection show a message, i've been using this code, but can't make it work,

CODE:

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    connection.connect();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // IN THIS PART I ADDED A TOAST, TO SHOW A MESSAGE WHEN THERE NO CONNECTION BUT IT ALWAYS SHOWS IT WHEATER THERE IS OR NOT.
    return false;
 }
}
```

using the same code i added at the beggining a condition

IF:

```
   if (!isConnectedToServer("http://vil/ong.php", 60)) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .setTitle("Connected")
                .setMessage("You are connected to server")
                .create().show();
    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .setTitle("Not Connected")
                .setMessage("You are not connected to server")
                .create().show();
    }
```

EXCEPTION:

I got an error

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to http://vil/ong.php (port 80) after 60ms
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:438)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:105)
  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1333)
  at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1412)
  at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:481)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:462)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:368)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
  at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.Reportes.isConnectedToServer(Reportes.java:408)
  at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.Reportes.onMapReady(Reportes.java:110)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
  at er.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:20)
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:5)
  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11951434:5)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

But AGAIN it show the same message, for both cases, so i really don't know why is this happening, i'd really appreciate some help on how to solve this.

Comment: You should not catch it as Exception, try handling as IOException because connectionTimeout exception fall under IOException and try printing the stacktrace for the exception you'll find what the exception is pointing to

Comment: Doing this, it keeps on throwing the same message :/

Comment: whats the exception you are getting. Print the stacktrace and show me

Comment: Done, i've already updated the post with the exception

Comment: U are making a service call but you didn't give the requestMethod (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)

Comment: `// IN THIS PART I ADDED A TOAST, TO SHOW A MESSAGE WHEN THERE NO CONNECTION BUT IT ALWAYS SHOWS IT WHEATER THERE IS OR NOT.
`. That is not possible if you have that internet code in a thread or asynctask. the toast would crash your app.

Comment: Thanks @greenapps i didn't know that, it's not a toast it's an alert dialog

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar is it necessary to give the requestMethod or how is this affecting the performance? Im new on it.

Comment: An alert dialog would crash your app to.

Comment: I used it and i can see it, the app doesnt stop anyway i remove it and called the method like its shown in the post using the condition @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

You get a `SocketTimeoutException`, that means that connecting to your URL takes too much time. Therefore Java enters your `catch` block, and returns `false`.

You need to check if you have access to the internet, and that your URL is correct. Also note that a `Toast` only can be displayed from the UI thread, and network operations should be called on a different thread; not the UI thread. Since your `Toast` was showing, I assume that you do network operations on the UI thread which is wrong.

Comment: Yes i hace access to internet, the thing that i do to check this, its to change the password to access to the database and so the message to show should be the one that it says "No connection" but in both cases the message its the same